# List index out of bounds: 0

Tags: apex-code

I have declared a two dimensional array "S" in a class as follows:

```
public class TestClass {

private static final List<List<Long>> S = new List<List<Long>>{};

Public TestClass {
}


public void setKey(string key, string keylength) {
integer i, j

for ( i = 0; i < 4; ++i ){        
        for ( j = 0; j < 256; ++j ){
   S[i][j] = 0;
}
}
}
}
```

Im getting a List index out of bounds: 0 at this line:

```
 S[i][j] = 0;
```

It seems that its not calling the List correctly,

Can someone please tell me what's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience in apex-code, but I'd guess that you haven't initialised the List elsewhere in the code, or at least not initialised the inner List.

Putting this in context with a well known language such as C# or Java, the initialisation would look something like this:

```
// ** NOTE: Pseudo-code **
// Loop over the outer List first
for ( i = 0; i < 4; ++i ){        
    // Initialise each List index as a new List, storing 256 integers.
    S[i] = new List<long>(new int[256]);

        // Loop over the newly initialised inner List, setting the int values.
        for ( j = 0; j < 256; ++j ){
            S[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this loop is suppose to be the initialization step for the array. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You mean long NOT integer in your outer loop definition. But I'm getting the same error for the code line you gave me  S[i] = new List<long>(new long[256]); it tells me "List index out of bounds: 0"

Comment: This means that `S[0]` isn't yet initialised. You'll have to initialise the outer array where you declare it (with `new ...`)